# Ply VS Jflex+Cup

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, ply, jflex, cup

I'm trying to build a compiler for a Pascal like language, and trying to decide between Ply(python) or a combination of Jflex+Cup(Java). I can't find any proper materials in order to evaluate which one is better.

I want to know about performance, ease of use and how large the communities around each are.

From what I can gather, the Java options to build compilers and parsers in general seem to be used more, but for these one's in particular, Ply seems to be much more widely used.

Which one is better?

Comment: This is either asking for opinions (which is out of scope) or for an objective evaluation based on no information whatsoever of the context. About the only generic advice which can be given is 'if you know one language better than the other, go with that one."